# Order Relation ACF by post_title

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

My meta_query is ordering just by ID, but I need order by the post_title

Heres the query I'm using

```
<?php
                                    $args = array(
                                        'orderby'        => 'meta_value',       // Or post by custom field
                                        'order'          => 'DESC',       // Or post by custom field
                                        'meta_key'       => 'case-solucao',
                                        'post_type'      => 'testemunho',          // Just the post type
                                        'posts_per_page' => -1,                 // Show all available post
                                    );
                                        query_posts($args);
                                        while(have_posts()){
                                            the_post();
                                            $solucoesCases = get_field('case-solucao');
                                            foreach ($solucoesCases as $solCase) {
                                                // echo count($solCase->ID);

                                            }
                                            echo $solCase->ID ." - ". $solCase->post_title."\n";
                                        }
                                    ?>
```

I have a Custon Field that's link the solution to post_type. But Its only sort by ID, and I need to sort by Post_title.
I'm really lost. Hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If, I'm correct, you need to display the title along the your custom field.

```
$args = array(
   'orderby'        => 'title',        // This will order the post by title
   'post_type'      => 'testemunho',   // Just the post type
   'posts_per_page' => -1,             // Show all available post
);
query_posts($args);
while(have_posts()){
    the_post();
    foreach ($solucoesCases as $solCase) {
        $solucoesCases = get_field('case-solucao', $solCase->ID ); // add the ID of the post_type
        echo $solCase->ID ." - ". $solCase->post_title."\n"; // will print all the title
        echo $solucoesCases;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try it, and then I'll tell you if its worked for me.